# Increase the size (height) of the title area in ColorBox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm using ColorBox to create a slideshow with fairly long titles

```
<a class="slideshow" href="image.gif" 
title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam iaculis velit 
eget augue tincidunt a tempor risus volutpat. Integer tempor sapien justo. Ut 
facilisis odio nec risus aliquet nec rhoncus nunc ultrices. Nulla facilisi. Ut ac 
ligula a metus rhoncus feugiat. Praesent lacinia diam neque, sed tempor felis. Morbi 
sed sapien sem, vitae pulvinar nunc. Fusce metus dolor, iaculis eget venenatis a, 
gravida sed tellus." rel="slides">Slideshow</a>
```

and the lightbox works, but in all the examples, there is not a lot of space set aside for the title.  How do I make the the title area larger so ColorBox properly sizes the lightbox "elastic" window?

---

Figured out a decent workaround solution.  I was able to move the "title" into the picture with a grayed out background by overriding some of the styles from `colorbox.css`.

```css
#cboxTitle { 
    text-align:justify !important;
    width:98.5% !important; 
    margin-bottom:24px !important;
    padding:5px !important;
    background-color:#333 !important;
    opacity:0.75 !important;
    filter:alpha(opacity=75) !important;
    color:#fff !important;
}
```

I based these overrides on the style provided in example 1.

Comment: Can you provide a demo ?

Comment: You should answer this yourself. Your workaround works fine.

Comment: This question answers itself better than the one provided answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hit the same issue. The solution is to force some «outerHeight» on #cboxContent, which will be substracted from the available height of the image.

So:

```
#cboxContent {
    padding-bottom:50px;
}
```

Considering #cboxTitle should be absolute, you can then fix its height too:

```
#cboxTitle {
    height:50px;
}
```